# Inflector rules - Table without underscore in db

Tags: cakephp, model, inflector

I have a simple problem and I don't know how to solve it.
I work with an existing database, where tables don't match with cakePHP conventions, and I have to make cakePHP work with it.

For example, I have a table named "ItiConf" in sql db (instead of iti_confs by convention).

My model *ItiConfModel.php* :

```
class ItiConf extends AppModel { 
}
```

My controller *ItiConfsController.php* :

```
class ItiConfsController extends AppController {
//...
}
```

I tried to make my own Inflector::rules in app/Config/bootstrap.php file,
but it doesn't work and I still have the following error :

```
*Error: Table iti_confs for model ItiConf was not found in datasource default.*
```

Do you please have any idea or hint about this problem and the synthax of the related inflector rule needed ?

Thanks you by advance !

Inset07.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Cake has its conventions, it doesn't require them to be used. In this case, try the `$useTable` property to change the table the model uses, instead of modifying Inflector rules:

```
class ItiConf extends AppModel { 

    public $useTable = 'ItiConf';

}
```

More info here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable